# unable to switch between workspaces

Tags: 12.04, workspaces

I unlocked my workspace icon from the launcher with the assumption I could just use ctrl+alt+arrow keys to navigate between workspaces. Now ctrl+alt+arrow keys won't switch between screens, and I cannot find the icon to launch it. Any ideas? I have went into the keyboard shortcut and verified that is the correct shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I tried **unity --reset** in the terminal and that corrected the problem. I still can't find the icon but I can switch between the workspaces using the hotkeys.

Comment: Newer (13-14) Ubuntu versions might need dconf-tools for unity reset. 
`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools; dconf reset -f /org/compiz/; setsid unity`

For icons reset: `unity --reset-icons` should do just fine, for both newer and older Ubuntu versions (12-14).